# Unhandled Runtime Error while executing a JS code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, undefined, typeerror

On my Localhost:3000, when I am running the code, I am getting an error saying:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

For the Source part, it is showing a certain section of my code, which is:-

```
    ;(async () => {
  20 |     setSelectedMarketNft(
> 21 |       listings.find((marketNft) => marketNft.asset?.id === selectedNft.id)
     |                                                                       ^
  22 |     )
  23 |   })()
  24 | }, [selectedNft, listings, isListed])
```

There are certain questions of the similar type on stackOverflow, but I am unable to find any answers from any of them. I am making a web3 project, where I am using next.js, sanity and thirweb.

The source code that contains this is:-

```
 const MakeOffer = ({ isListed, selectedNft, listings, marketPlaceModule }) => {
  const [selectedMarketNft, setSelectedMarketNft] = useState()
  const [enableButton, setEnableButton] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!listings || isListed === 'false') return
    ;(async () => {
      setSelectedMarketNft(
        listings.find((marketNft) => marketNft.asset?.id === selectedNft.id)
      )
    })()
  }, [selectedNft, listings, isListed])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!selectedMarketNft || !selectedNft) return

    setEnableButton(true)
  }, [selectedMarketNft, selectedNft])
```

Link to the full source code of the file where this error is occuring is:-
https://github.com/hemang-h/Standard-Demo-Marketplace-and-Minting/blob/main/components/nft/Purchase.js

Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong here?

**EXTRAS**
Just for a better understanding, this is the full source code of the file where I am facing this error:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { HiTag } from 'react-icons/hi'
import { IoMdWallet } from 'react-icons/io'
import toast, { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast'

const style = {
  button: `mr-8 flex items-center py-2 px-12 rounded-lg cursor-pointer`,
  buttonIcon: `text-xl`,
  buttonText: `ml-2 text-lg font-semibold`,
}

const MakeOffer = ({ isListed, selectedNft, listings, marketPlaceModule }) => {
  const [selectedMarketNft, setSelectedMarketNft] = useState()
  const [enableButton, setEnableButton] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!listings || isListed === 'false') return
    ;(async () => {
      setSelectedMarketNft(
        listings.find((marketNft) => marketNft.asset?.id === selectedNft.id)
      )
    })()
  }, [selectedNft, listings, isListed])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!selectedMarketNft || !selectedNft) return

    setEnableButton(true)
  }, [selectedMarketNft, selectedNft])

  const confirmPurchase = (toastHandler = toast) =>
    toastHandler.success(`Purchase successful!`, {
      style: {
        background: '#04111d',
        color: '#fff',
      },
    })

  const buyItem = async (
    listingId = selectedMarketNft.id,
    quantityDesired = 1,
    module = marketPlaceModule
  ) => {
    console.log(listingId, quantityDesired, module, 'david')
    // yo RAZA lets goooo!!!
    //yo Qazi, ok
    // sure okay about to run it...
    // just clicked buy now...
    // still error
    // where can i see the contract address of the marketplace module
    // in [nftId.js]
    await module
      .buyoutDirectListing({
        listingId: listingId,
        quantityDesired: quantityDesired,
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))

    confirmPurchase()
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex h-20 w-full items-center rounded-lg border border-[#151c22] bg-[#303339] px-12">
      <Toaster position="bottom-left" reverseOrder={false} />
      {isListed === 'true' ? (
        <>
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              enableButton ? buyItem(selectedMarketNft.id, 1) : null
            }}
            className={`${style.button} bg-[#2081e2] hover:bg-[#42a0ff]`}
          >
            <IoMdWallet className={style.buttonIcon} />
            <div className={style.buttonText}>Buy Now</div>
          </div>
          <div
            className={`${style.button} border border-[#151c22]  bg-[#363840] hover:bg-[#4c505c]`}
          >
            <HiTag className={style.buttonIcon} />
            <div className={style.buttonText}>Make Offer</div>
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        <div className={`${style.button} bg-[#2081e2] hover:bg-[#42a0ff]`}>
          <IoMdWallet className={style.buttonIcon} />
          <div className={style.buttonText}>List Item</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default MakeOffer
```

Comment: selectedNft is undefined. Find out why it is undefined

Comment: @EpicProgrammer It is defined, 
`const MakeOffer = ({ isListed, selectedNft, listings, marketPlaceModule }) => {
  const [selectedMarketNft, setSelectedMarketNft] = useState()
  const [enableButton, setEnableButton] = useState(false)`

Comment: Can you share a [mre] of your code in the body of your question as prescribed by [ask]?

Comment: @esqew I was actually doing that xD; but stackoverflow is getting down again and again. But now it's done :)

Comment: @HemangJoshi Can you share an example of how you're *invoking* this method? Your interpreter seems to think that whatever you're passing in as an argument here doesn't contain `selectedNft` as you seem to think it should - it would help to see your invocation with some mocked up data to understand why this may be.

Comment: @esqew Alright! So I am actually calling an "IIFE" inside "MakeOffer" function , where basically I am looking for the marketNFT which is looking for the selectedNFT and if it matches, then I set it as selectedMarketNFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is solved, turns out that I just had to add

```
if(!selectedNft) return;
```

to successfully run my code. Final code will be as:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { HiTag } from 'react-icons/hi'
import { IoMdWallet } from 'react-icons/io'
import toast, { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast'

const style = {
  button: `mr-8 flex items-center py-2 px-12 rounded-lg cursor-pointer`,
  buttonIcon: `text-xl`,
  buttonText: `ml-2 text-lg font-semibold`,
}

const MakeOffer = ({ isListed, selectedNft, listings, marketPlaceModule }) => {
  const [selectedMarketNft, setSelectedMarketNft] = useState()
  const [enableButton, setEnableButton] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!selectedNft) return;
    if (!listings || isListed === 'false') return
    ;(async () => {
      setSelectedMarketNft(
        listings.find((marketNft) => marketNft.asset?.id === selectedNft.id)
      )
    })()
  }, [selectedNft, listings, isListed])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!selectedMarketNft || !selectedNft) return

    setEnableButton(true)
  }, [selectedMarketNft, selectedNft])

  const confirmPurchase = (toastHandler = toast) =>
    toastHandler.success(`Purchase successful!`, {
      style: {
        background: '#04111d',
        color: '#fff',
      },
    })

  const buyItem = async (
    listingId = selectedMarketNft.id,
    quantityDesired = 1,
    module = marketPlaceModule
  ) => {
    console.log(listingId, quantityDesired, module, 'david')
    // yo RAZA lets goooo!!!
    //yo Qazi, ok
    // sure okay about to run it...
    // just clicked buy now...
    // still error
    // where can i see the contract address of the marketplace module
    // in [nftId.js]
    await module
      .buyoutDirectListing({
        listingId: listingId,
        quantityDesired: quantityDesired,
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))

    confirmPurchase()
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex h-20 w-full items-center rounded-lg border border-[#151c22] bg-[#303339] px-12">
      <Toaster position="bottom-left" reverseOrder={false} />
      {isListed === 'true' ? (
        <>
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              enableButton ? buyItem(selectedMarketNft.id, 1) : null
            }}
            className={`${style.button} bg-[#2081e2] hover:bg-[#42a0ff]`}
          >
            <IoMdWallet className={style.buttonIcon} />
            <div className={style.buttonText}>Buy Now</div>
          </div>
          <div
            className={`${style.button} border border-[#151c22]  bg-[#363840] hover:bg-[#4c505c]`}
          >
            <HiTag className={style.buttonIcon} />
            <div className={style.buttonText}>Make Offer</div>
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        <div className={`${style.button} bg-[#2081e2] hover:bg-[#42a0ff]`}>
          <IoMdWallet className={style.buttonIcon} />
          <div className={style.buttonText}>List Item</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default MakeOffer
```

Answer (score 0):

selectedNFT is undefined as mentioned above.

The issue could be that it is running your code before it's defined.

This may go in your return function:

```
      {(typeof selectedNFT != 'undefined') ? (
        <div>Code that fetches from selectedNFT goes here.</div>
      ): (
        <div>This could be a loading bar..</div>
      )}
```

This will run your code ONLY after everything else executes.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by console seletedNft inside makeoffer component to make sure you are getting props correctly and also check if its return object which has key  with name "id" . Its cannot read id property in your selectedNft make sure its exist . I hope its help.